# DRF Non-field errors: Unable to log in with provided credentials

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, djoser

I am struggling to understand why my app suddenly wont allow me to log in a user after any changes are made to their profile. I have a nested User serializer with the profile serializer fields (onetoOne) using Djoser for the urls. When I try to update the user profile from the api endpoint it updates but throws an error that the avatar has no file associated to it. I thought that if I added "required=False" to to the ProfileSerializer it would negate this behaviour. Please help it is driving me crazy, I have googled and not found the answer why. I think it is in my create method within my UserSerializer class. It is also not saving the avatar if any of the other fields are changed within the profile object. Very strange. It was all working fine and for some reason now its not logging in users.

Here is the model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    residence = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    active_id = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to ='uploads/profile_pics/',default='uploads/default.jpg')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.avatar.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.avatar.path)
```

Here is the serializers:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)    

    class Meta:
        model = Profile       
        fields = ("__all__")
        
class ProfileStatusSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    # user_profile = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ProfileStatus       
        fields = "__all__"

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer(required=False, allow_null=True, partial=True)
    parser_class = (FileUploadParser,)
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'profile','password', 'id']
        extra_kwargs = {"password":{'write_only': True}}


    def update(self, instance, validated_data):

        if 'profile' in validated_data:
            nested_serializer = self.fields['profile']
            nested_instance = instance.profile
            nested_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
            nested_serializer.update(nested_instance, nested_data)

        return super(UserSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data) 

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return User.objects.create_user(
            username = validated_data['username'], # HERE
            password = validated_data['password'])
```

Please halp.

Comment: Try to add `validated_data.pop('password')` before `nested_serializer.update` and see if it works (this will prevent changing the password during update). It seems you are overwriting the user's password in `update` (setting it to the unhashed password) causing your login problem

Comment: No, its still the same error unfortunately

Comment: Oh sorry i meant before `super(UserSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)`. But this time try to create the user first before doing any update. You might be working on an already broken user password

Comment: I have tried this before. Still the same non field error. I think it has something to do with the profile fields

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
I needed to add validated_data fields to the create method.

```
def create(self, validated_data):
        return User.objects.create_user(
           validated_data['username'],None,validated_data['password'])
```